# subset fail on np.meshgrid generated dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I generate a dataframe for lonlat like this

```
a=np.arange(89.7664, 89.7789, 1e-4)
b=np.arange(20.6897, 20.7050, 1e-4)
temp_arr=np.array(np.meshgrid(a, b)).T.reshape(-1, 2)
np_df=pd.DataFrame(temp_arr, columns = ['lon','lat'])
```

and it create the dataframe I want

[image]

When I tried to subset the first lon

```
len(np_df[np_df['lon']==89.7664])
```

it will return 153. But when I tried subset some last lon

```
len(np_df[np_df['lon']==89.7788])
```

it will return 0

I wonder what is wrong here. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) if compare floats within a tolerance:

```
len(np_df[np.isclose(np_df['lon'], 89.7788)])
```

If still not working integers with multiple by 10000 and cast to ints should help:

```
len(np_df[np_df['lon'].mul(10000).astype(int).eq(897788)])
```

Comment: Thank you, I got some length but it is like 1377 data. Is it because I use float for this, so it cant compare with exactly same number?

Comment: @d_frEak - exactly. If still no match try change `rtol` and `atol` parameters

Comment: oh thanks, I think I will try to change it into integer then, maybe I can get the exact number